# Which one to use NSOperation main() and start() methods

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsoperation

By Apple Documentation

Main -

> For non-concurrent operations, you typically override only one method:
>
> main

Start -

> When you add an operation to an operation queue, the queue ignores the
>   value of the asynchronous property and always calls the start method
>   from a separate thread. Therefore, if you always run operations by
>   adding them to an operation queue, there is no reason to make them
>   asynchronous.

If i have to execute the code of Alamofire which already uses a operation queue and is asynchronous. Where should i write the code (Main or Start) to call Alamofire request.?

Comment: Have you read the extensive descriptions of those two functions in the documentation for `NSOperation`? If so, what exactly aren't you sure about?

Comment: I made the question specific to my needs. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I did not grab the point of your answer, but, if you need to wrap Alamofire in your custom operation, you must create an asynchronous `NSOperation`.

You can find a very good example of this in [this Github repo](https://github.com/robertmryan/Operation-Test-Swift).

The key point are:

- override the `asynchronous` property returning `true`
- override the `start` method
- take control of the `isExecuting` and `isFinished` properties in order to change the state of the operation

Answer (score -1):

Well you could implement both `Main` and `Start` as one line functions that each call `MyRealProcessingFunction` which does your real work.